# AWS eventbridge rule failed invocations - where can I see why it failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-auto-scaling

I created a rule in eventbridge to call ssm automation doc at the instance launch lifecycle in auto-scaling group but it's failing to call the ssm doc. where can i see the log for this or find out why it failed?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a dead-letter queue to your rule’s target, and then view the attributes of the message placed on the DLQ to see the error message EventBridge receives from the target.

You can read more about adding a DLQ here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rule-dlq.html

Note, it’s worth setting your retry count to 0 while you’re debugging, otherwise you’ll have to wait for EventBridge to exhaust the default 24hrs of retries before it places the event on the DLQ.

Comment: thanks for the note. I was wondering why I haven't receiving anything to the DLQ then I saw your note :)